# Client node cannot connect to server

Tags: c#, ignite

I'm using Ignite.NET 2.7.6, I have one server node and many client ones. After some time(several days) some client nodes fail connecting to the server one. The only thing that helps is to restart the server.

Ok, if it's the connection issue, so the restart wouldn't work, but it helps, so I don't understand what's wrong.

Here is the log from the server node where the client becomes disconnected:

```
[23:13:17,028][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-#3][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35, rmtPort=61608]
[23:13:17,028][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-#3][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35, rmtPort=61608]
[23:13:17,029][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#1093][TcpDiscoverySpi] Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35:61608, rmtPort=61608]
[23:13:17,034][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#1093][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35:61608, rmtPort=61608
[23:13:17,437][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-#3][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35, rmtPort=61630]
[23:13:17,437][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-#3][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35, rmtPort=61630]
[23:13:17,438][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#1095][TcpDiscoverySpi] Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35:61630, rmtPort=61630]
[23:13:17,467][INFO][disco-event-worker-#72][GridDiscoveryManager] Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=40bdc648-b25f-4b16-ac39-013bd7390416, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.22.35], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, BB-REC-VIP.ast.loc/192.168.22.35:0], discPort=0, order=477, intOrder=257, lastExchangeTime=1581613997440, loc=false, ver=2.7.6#20190911-sha1:21f7ca41, isClient=true]
[23:13:17,468][INFO][disco-event-worker-#72][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=477, locNode=4fdcbe35, servers=1, clients=36, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=162, offheap=16.0GB, heap=27.0GB]
[23:13:17,468][INFO][disco-event-worker-#72][GridDiscoveryManager]   ^-- Baseline [id=3, size=4, online=1, offline=3]
[23:13:17,468][INFO][exchange-worker-#73][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=477, minorTopVer=0], mvccCrd=MvccCoordinator [nodeId=4fdcbe35-8390-4584-92a4-8d918625540e, crdVer=1581589948994, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=0]], mvccCrdChange=false, crd=true, evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=40bdc648-b25f-4b16-ac39-013bd7390416, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
[23:13:17,469][INFO][exchange-worker-#73][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=477, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=477, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
[23:13:17,470][INFO][exchange-worker-#73][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Completed partition exchange [localNode=4fdcbe35-8390-4584-92a4-8d918625540e, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=477, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=40bdc648-b25f-4b16-ac39-013bd7390416, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.22.35], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, BB-REC-VIP.ast.loc/192.168.22.35:0], discPort=0, order=477, intOrder=257, lastExchangeTime=1581613997440, loc=false, ver=2.7.6#20190911-sha1:21f7ca41, isClient=true], done=true], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=477, minorTopVer=0], durationFromInit=0]
[23:13:17,470][INFO][exchange-worker-#73][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=477, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
[23:13:17,489][INFO][exchange-worker-#73][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=477, minorTopVer=0], force=false, evt=NODE_JOINED, node=40bdc648-b25f-4b16-ac39-013bd7390416]
[23:13:37,550][WARNING][grid-timeout-worker-#47][TcpDiscoverySpi] Socket write has timed out (consider increasing 'sockTimeout' configuration property) [sockTimeout=20000, rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35:61630, rmtPort=61630, sockTimeout=20000]
[23:13:37,550][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#1095][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.22.35:61630, rmtPort=61630
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: From the provided log, I see that the client was connected. It will be great to provide the logs where the client was disconnected. Full server logs will be useful too. BTW you said about one node cluster but I see that your baseline contains 4 - Baseline [id=3, size=4, online=1, offline=3]. Some partitions located on offline nodes and it can be a problem for you. You can read https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology.

Comment: The server is in replicated mode, all offline servers are offline for a long time, it was an experiment that ended. About "where the client was disconnected": I made mistake - this is the log for the server node, where this client becomes disconnected

Comment: "[23:13:17,467][INFO][disco-event-worker-#72][GridDiscoveryManager] Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=40bdc648-b25f-4b16-ac39-013bd7390416, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.22.35], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, BB-REC-VIP.ast.loc/192.168.22.35:0], discPort=0, order=477, intOrder=257, lastExchangeTime=1581613997440, loc=false, ver=2.7.6#20190911-sha1:21f7ca41, isClient=true]" - It means that client was connected to cluster. (isClient=true) and (Added new node to topology) messages show it. Please re-check your logs. It should contain the NODE_LEFT or NODE_FAILED messages in the server logs.

Comment: "Finished serving remote node connection" this doesn't mean that the client's connection was closed? I'll check again when it will occur next time, thanks

Comment: Not really. It just means that some TCP connection was closed. For example, one node requests the metrics or some task results from another node. After receiving the results the connection can be closed. You should investigate the logs where the server will write that some node was disconnected or left the cluster. It should also produce the changing of the topology (Topology snapshot message). Please try to grep the server logs for  NODE_LEFT or NODE_FAILED messages and provide them.